# How to connect to SQL Server from Firebase function using Windows authentication

Tags: node.js, sql-server, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use the `mssql` package to connect to SQL Server from a Firebase function.

After quite a bit of work with google and our team here we finally got the virtual network piece working so that the cloud function can connect to our on premise database.

Now that that piece is working, I am getting an invalid login because I can't get windows authentication enabled.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#microsoft--contributors-node-v8-driver-for-nodejs-for-sql-server

I believe this says that I need to us the msnodesqlv8 package so that I can specify the trustedConnection option.  When I do that, however, my function wont deploy b/c I believe the firebase host is linux and msnodesql8 is only supported on win32.

Any ideas what to try here?

> Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`npm_install` had stderr output:\nnpm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM\nnpm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for msnodesqlv8@0.8.5: wanted {\"os\":\"win32\",\"arch\":\"any\"} (current: {\"os\":\"linux\",\"arch\":\"x64\"})\nnpm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32\nnpm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any\nnpm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux\nnpm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2019-11-22T14_21_54_400Z-debug.log\n\nerror: `npm_install` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "69095663"}}

Comment: You probably just need to use a SQL Server login instead. **Windows** authentication is never going to be able to work from a Linux machine really, especially if it's not even in the same network. There are ways to get Linux machines to join Windows domains I believe, but not sure if that extends to Kerberbos/Windows auth working across the board. Put it in the "too difficult" box and just set up a SQL login.

Comment: Thanks, this is what we're doing.  I didn't realize that would even be an option for me.